# Flatten multidimensional assoc array (decoded from JSON)

Tags: php, arrays, json, csv, flatten

I have JSON object like this:

```
{
  "chats": [
    {
    "type": "chat",
    "visitor": {
      "id": "S1506042519.608fc390eb",
      "name": "Visitor"
    },
    "agents": [
      {
        "display_name": "Agent",
        "email": "agent@example.com"
      }
    ],
    "chat_start_url": "https://example.com/",
    "group": [
      3, 4
    ],
    "messages": [
    {
      "author_name": "Agent",
      "text": "Hello. How may I help you?",
      "welcome_message": true
    },
    {
      "author_name": "Visitor",
      "text": "transfer me to agent"
    },
    {
      "author_name": "Agent",
      "text": "Hello. How may I help you?"
    },
    {
      "author_name": "Visitor",
      "text": "transfer me to agent"
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "type": "chat",
    "visitor": {
      "id": "S1506042519.608fc390eb",
      "name": "Visitor"
    },
    "agents": [
      {
        "display_name": "Agent",
        "email": "agent@example.com"
      }
    ],
    "chat_start_url": "https://example.com/",
    "group": [
      3, 4
    ],
    "messages": [
    {
      "author_name": "Agent",
      "text": "Hello. How may I help you?",
      "welcome_message": true
    },
    {
      "author_name": "Visitor",
      "text": "transfer me to agent"
    }
    ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to write this object to CSV file, but with specific formatting. What I want to have as result is showed on this website: https://json-csv.com/
Just copy my JSON to see it, here is quick screenshot: http://take.ms/p2FAI

**The question** is how to properly refactor the array to get this output:

```
$refactoredArray = array(
    0 => array(
        "chats_type",
        "chats_visitor_id",
        "chats_visitor_name",
        "chats_agents_display_name",
        "chats_agents_name",
        "chats_start_url",
        "chats_group_1",
        "chats_group_2",
        "chats_messages_author_name",
        "chats_messages_text",
        "chats_messages_welcome_message"
    ), 
    1 => array(
        "chat",
        "S1506042519.608fc390eb",
        "Visitor",
        "Agent",
        "agent@example.com",
        "https://example.com/",
        3,
        4,
        "Agent",
        "Hello. How may I help you?",
        true
    ),
    2 => array(
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "Visitor",
        "transfer me to agent",
        ""
    ),
    3 => array(
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "Agent",
        "Hello. How may I help you?",
        ""
    ),
    4 => array(
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "Visitor",
        "transfer me to agent",
        ""
    ),
    5 => array(
        "chat",
        "S1506042519.608fc390eb",
        "Visitor",
        "Agent",
        "agent@example.com",
        "https://example.com/",
        3,
        4,
        "Agent",
        "Hello. How may I help you?",
        true
    ),
    6 => array(
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "Visitor",
        "transfer me to agent",
        ""
    )
);
```

Any ideas :c ? I totally can't flatten the array correctly so I could put it to CSV file.

Comment: @mickmackusa the easiest way to show what I want to acheive is to visit this link:
https://json-csv.com/

And just copy-paste my JSON object. It's easier to show than explain it for me :-)

Comment: However, thanks for the tip! The problem is that I totally don't know how bite this cake :/

Comment: Let me refactor it to make it smaller.

Comment: @mickmackusa I had updated expected PHP array however, I totally don't know how to convert it from JSON object. I feel the answer is easy, but I just can't get the right path to find it. I just feel dumb :/

Comment: Have a good one, for now I will try to follow @LeMeme tips. Thanks for for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it, here is function that parse it exactly how https://json-csv.com/ does it.

```
function json2array($array) {

    $flat = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $chatID = 0;
            foreach ($value as $chatsKey => $chatsValue) {
                foreach ($chatsValue as $singleChatKey => $singleChatValue) {
                    if(is_array($singleChatValue)) {
                        $chatPropID = 0;
                        foreach ($singleChatValue as $chatPropKey => $chatPropValue) {
                            $maxPropID = 0;
                            if ($chatPropKey > $maxPropID)
                                $maxPropID = $chatPropKey;
                            if(is_array($chatPropValue)) {
                                foreach ($chatPropValue as $lastPropKey => $lastPropValue) {
                                    $flat[ $chatID+$chatPropKey ][ $key . '_' . $singleChatKey . '_' . $lastPropKey ] = $lastPropValue;
                                }
                            } else {
                                $flat[ $chatID ][ $key . '_' . $singleChatKey . '_' . $chatPropKey ] = $chatPropValue;
                            }

                            $chatPropID++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $flat[ $chatID ][ $key . '_' . $singleChatKey ] = $singleChatValue;
                    }
                }
                $chatID += $maxPropID + 2;
            }
        } else
            $flat[0][$key] = $value;
    }

    return $flat;
}
```

Thank you guys for help <3

Answer (score 0):

i hope you already resolve that issue, if not i'm attaching some code, to get you an idea, what i did was, first decode the json output you are getting, then, reading that output and going as deep as needed, using an associative array to flatten your response, the code is not complete, but it working and will get you started, hope you get lucky!

```
$jsonvalue = json_decode('{
  "chats": [{
      "type": "chat",
      "visitor": {
        "id": "S1506042519.608fc390eb",
        "name": "Visitor"
      },
      "agents": [
        {
          "display_name": "Agent",
          "email": "agent@example.com"
        }
      ],
      "chat_start_url": "https://example.com/",
      "group": [
        3, 4
      ],
      "messages": [
        {
          "author_name": "Agent",
          "text": "Hello. How may I help you?",
          "welcome_message": true
        },
        {
          "author_name": "Visitor",
          "text": "transfer me to agent"
        },
        {
          "author_name": "Agent",
          "text": "Hello. How may I help you?"
        },
        {
          "author_name": "Visitor",
          "text": "transfer me to agent"
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "type": "chat",
      "visitor": {
        "id": "S1506042519.608fc390eb",
        "name": "Visitor"
      },
      "agents": [
        {
          "display_name": "Agent",
          "email": "agent@example.com"
        }
      ],
      "chat_start_url": "https://example.com/",
      "group": [
        3, 4
      ],
      "messages": [
        {
          "author_name": "Agent",
          "text": "Hello. How may I help you?",
          "welcome_message": true
        },
        {
          "author_name": "Visitor",
          "text": "transfer me to agent"
        }
      ]
    }]
}');
    $flatArray = [];
    $chatID = 0;
    foreach ($jsonvalue as $chats) {
        foreach ($chats as $chatProperty) {
            $flatArray[$chatID] = $chatID;
            $flatArray['chatType'] = $chatProperty->type;
            //visitor
            $flatArray['visitorID'] = $chatProperty->visitor->id;
            $flatArray['visitorName'] = $chatProperty->visitor->name;

            foreach ($chatProperty->group as $groupValue) {
                $flatArray['group_' . $groupValue] = $groupValue;
                echo $groupValue;
            }

            foreach ($chatProperty->messages as $value) {
                $flatArray['author_name'] = $value->author_name;
                $flatArray['text'] = $value->text;
                $flatArray['welcome_message'] = isset($value->welcome_message) ?
                    $value->welcome_message : 'no welcome message';
            }
            $chatID++;
        }
    }

    var_dump($flatArray);
```

Comment: Hi @LeMeme, I'm not sure if I get your answer. I have updated my initial question - can you have a look and give me some more tips here?

Comment: THANK YOU! I needed some fresh view from another person. I had improved your idea and make my own function, I pasted it in a reply below.

Comment: that's awesome, man, good luck, json conversion is always kind of a pain